# Error using scipy's fsolve when one of the variables is an array

Tags: python, scipy-optimize

I am trying to use f solve on a set of equations:

1. xa + xb = x
2. xa/xb = (CA/CB)e^-(F/RT)*(E0_A-E0_B). I intend to solve for xa and xb but x itself is an array as shown below. I have tried to do this but keep getting an error. I dont know where I am getting it wrong.

```
from scipy.optimize import fsolve
import numpy as np
x = np.array([0.01394346, 0.01727623, 0.02139363, 0.02647018, 0.03271463,
       0.04037362, 0.04974189, 0.06113669, 0.07489298, 0.0914198 ,
       0.11119803, 0.13467519, 0.1622032 , 0.19409497, 0.23056969,
       0.27160588, 0.3169306 , 0.36594778, 0.41776317, 0.471372  ,
       0.5256699 , 0.5794641 , 0.63155216, 0.68075466, 0.72615373,
       0.767264  , 0.80389225, 0.8359975 , 0.8637226 , 0.8873593 ,
       0.9072883 , 0.92398256, 0.93792963, 0.9494987 , 0.95898896,
       0.96673596, 0.9730703 , 0.9782413 , 0.982436  , 0.9858274 ,
       0.9885736 , 0.99079704, 0.9925912 , 0.99403596, 0.99519914,
       0.99613607, 0.9968898 , 0.99749595, 0.9979841 , 0.99837816])
def eqs(p):
    R = 8.314
    F = 96485
    T = 298.15
    E0_A = 0.516
    E0_B = 0.393
    CA = 0.37
    CB = 0.63
    xa, xb = p
    return ((xa+xb)- x, (xa/xb)-(0.37/0.63)*np.exp(-(96485/(8.314*298.15))*(0.393-0.516)))

eqs((1,1))
fsolve(eqs, x0 = (1,1))
```

*ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars*

Comment: You said `xa+xb=x`, but xa and xb are integers.  How can that array be equal to 2?  I don't get what you're expecting here.  Are you trying to say `x` needs to be one of the values in that list?  Also, why define symbols if you're going to embed the constants anyway?

Comment: As per the documentation: "func: callable f(x, *args). A function that takes at least one (possibly vector) argument, and returns a value of the same length." (where 'func' is your `eqs`). If your input is an array of size two (don't use a tuple; make it an array), the result should be an array of size two. But your `x` value will make the output a 2-tuple (or len-2 array if converted) of arrays. Which isn't not equivalent in shape to the input `p`.

Comment: Yes thanks for your comment. I think this is where I got it wrong.